# Setting path for apache

Tags: apache2

I installed apache2 on my local machine, and when typing `which apache2` it returns:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2
```

And when trying setting path for apache2 by using the following command:

```
sudo apache2 -settingpath /usr/sbin/apache2
```

It failed! It failed because whenever I restart apache2 using `apache2 restart`, I always receive error message telling me that I used the wrong user id.

So could you help me set path for Apache http server on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

The Default path for apache is /var/wwww.

You can change it by Configuring

> httpd.conf

file. You can find it in

> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Comment: Hi Ketan Patel. Thank you for your answer. However, I want to configure the path to start apache. That is to say, I can simply type: apache2 restart, instead of /etc/init.d/apache2 restart.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to use the `-k` restart thus

```
sudo apache2 -k restart
```

To which you will be prompted for your password with which you log in.